# ASP .net core time out error using Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to ASP .Net Core and am working my way through a demo project to learn the tech stack.

My project is using .net core 2.2 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and Oracle.EntityFramework.Core.

I created a model and then went and scaffolded my view and controller through VS 2019. I've set up `ConfigureService(...)` to use Oracle. I added an HTML link on my main index page to hook into the view created for my model. When it calls the `Controller::Index()` function, I end up getting the following timeout error

`OracleException: Connection request timed out
OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager<PM, CP, PR>.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, bool bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, string affinityInstanceName, bool bForceMatch)`

Any help or guidance as to what I could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a error connecting to the database.
There are some things you should check:

1. Make sure the connection string to the database, stored in the appsettings.json is correct.
2. Make sure to have a firewall rule which allows inbound traffic to the port from where the Oracle db is listening.

If the problem persists then you should provide the code you are using to access the database.

Comment: I had to fix part of my connection string and then open a connection to pass into my DbContext. Thanks for the help!